# What is an Icy Word™?

Tags: knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Icy™** word.
Here is a list of Icy™ and Not Icy™ Words:

| Icy Word™ | Not Icy Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| DAMAGE | FIX |
| RUNNER | SLEEPER |
| DOVER | CALAIS |
| CUT | STICK |
| PROJECT | INJECT |
| VIDEO | OREO |
| BLAST | IMPLODE |
| COVER | REVEAL |

CSV version:

```
Icy Word™,Not Icy Word™
DAMAGE,FIX
RUNNER,SLEEPER
DOVER,CALAIS
CUT,STICK
PROJECT,INJECT
VIDEO,OREO
BLAST,IMPLODE
COVER,REVEAL
```

Hint:

> This puzzle is seasonal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An Icy Word is:

> A word whose first two letters also begin the name of one of **[Santa's reindeer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus%27s_reindeer)**!

Like so:

> **DA**MAGE = **DA**SHER or **DA**NCER,
>  **RU**NNER = **RU**DOLPH,
>  **DO**VER = **DO**NNER,
>  **CU**T = **CU**PID,
>  **PR**OJECT = **PR**ANCER,
>  **VI**DEO = **VI**XEN,
>  **BL**AST = **BL**ITZEN,
>  **CO**VER = **CO**MET

As for the title:

> 'Icy' is a very wintry word, perfect for describing the climate of Lapland, where we all know Santa and his reindeer live!

Comment: Hehe nice one.