# What is a Fair Word?

Tags: word, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Fair Word**. If it does not conform to this rule, I call it an **Unfair Word**.
Here is a list (not exhaustive) of some Fair Words and Unfair Words:

| Fair Words | Unfair Words |
| --- | --- |
| BEDSPREAD | DUVET |
| PRONUNCIATION | SPELLING |
| YETI | BIGFOOT |
| DEEP | HIGH |
| ICY | SOLID |
| DUPLICATE | CLOSURE |
| BADLY | WELL |
| EVERY | SINGLE |

CSV version:

```
Fair Words,Unfair Words
BEDSPREAD,DUVET        
PRONUNCIATION,SPELLING   
YETI,BIGFOOT      
DEEP,HIGH         
ICY,SOLID        
DUPLICATE,CLOSURE      
BADLY,WELL    
EVERY,SINGLE
```

**Main question**: find the rule which determines Fair Words and Unfair Words.

**Bonus question**: which of the above Fair Words is a Super-Fair Word?

**Hints** and further information:

- > The order of the words doesn't matter.
- > There is no significance in the particular choice of Unfair Words: they're just words vaguely similar to the Fair Words opposite them which are *not* Fair.
- > The meaning of the words doesn't matter.

Comment: Inspired by [this previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105972/5373) (one of the ideas I had to solve that one, which didn't work, became this one).

Comment: is the missing ™ intended?

Comment: @melfnt Yes - I don't like the idea of "trademarking" puzzles.

Comment: Is it relevant whether duplicate is regarded as a verb or a noun? Or is the outcome the same either way?

Comment: Argh almost got one, are you sure bedspread is not a mistake?

Comment: @Smartest1here Bedspread is not a mistake, but what was your attempt?

Comment: @feelinferrety I'm not sure if I should say ... revealing whether that's relevant or not would give some information about what *type* of word property we're looking for, e.g. whether it's about the words' meaning, letters, shape, grammar, ...

Comment: Right, it was to do with the phonetic 'E' sound that was contained in the pronunciation of the words. All the fair words had it except for bedspread and none of the unfair words had it.

Comment: @Smartest1here Ah, no that's way off, sorry.

Comment: Does the order of fair words and unfair words that you have here matter?

Comment: @RayDansh Nope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A word is Fair if

> when you convert the letters to numbers by A1Z26, it contains both *some number and its square*. BE**D**S**P**READ, PRONUN**CI**ATION, **YE**TI, **D**EE**P**, **IC**Y, **D**U**P**L**IC**ATE (this one is Super-Fair because it happens twice), **B**A**D**LY (this one is *kinda* Super-Fair if you count A/A...), **E**VER**Y**.

The name

> presumably comes from the idiom "fair and *square*".

OP indicates in comments that I guessed wrong about what counts as Super-Fair. Here's another possibility that works about as well:

> BEDSPREAD is Super-Fair because it has B^2=D and then D^2=P.

Comment: Congrats, you got it. Although you're not quite right on the bonus question (hint: I didn't consider happening twice *unconnectedly* to be a Super occurrence).

Comment: OK, then I have another proposal, edited into the answer.

Comment: Yep, that's the one I meant.